# Add a className onClick while removing other class with the same name from siblings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, classname

I need to have a class name added when clicked while removing the other classes with the same className from siblings.  Let's say I have

```
function Menu(props) {
    const list = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']
    const menuitems = list.map((list, index) => {
        return <li className="menuitem" key={index}>{list}</li>
    })

    return (
        <ul>{menuitems}</ul>
    )
}
```

In the DOM, it should look like:

```
<ul>
    <list class="menuitem">list1</li>
    <list class="menuitem active">list2</li>
    <list class="menuitem">list3</li>
</ul>
```

I'm still on familiarization state with ReactJS. So please help and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here I have created working demo for you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ertozp**

You can manage it by using `state` variable. You have to handle the click event of `li` tag and set `index` on click of it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

...
...

function App(props) {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(1)
    const list = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']
    const menuitems = list.map((list, index) => {
        return <li className={`menuitem${active === index ? ' active' :''}`} key={index} onClick={()=>setActive(index)}>{list}</li>
    })

    return (
        <ul>{menuitems}</ul>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const menuitems = list.map((list, index) => {
    return <li className=`menuitem ${someCheckHere && 'active'}` key={index}>{list}</li>
})
```